# Initialization of a pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm facing a problem initializing an array with pointers to members of a structure. The  structure members have to be accessed through a structure pointer. The reason for this is we initialize the pointer at runtime to a memory mapped address location. The following code snippet is an example of the problem;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  long* lp;
}T;

typedef struct
{
  long l;
}F;

F* f;

T t[] =
{
    { &f->l }
};

void init (void)
{
  f = (F*) 0x08000100; 
}

int main (void)
{
  init();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The compiler output is the following;

> ```
> gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c
> -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\Test.o ..\src\Test.c ..\src\Test.c:18: 
> error: initializer element is not constant
> ..\src\Test.c:18: error: (near initialization for `t[0].lp')
> ..\src\Test.c:18: error: initializer element is not constant
> ..\src\Test.c:18: error: (near initialization for `t[0]') 
> Build error occurred, build is stopped
> ```

The problem here is we initialize the pointer at runtime, the compiler doesn't know where it can find the structure members. We cannot work around the structure pointer as we don't wan't to use the linker script for this.

Any ideas how to get around this one?

Comment: Why typedef your structs?  they have a type already and you can use incomplete types to hide their content from external users.  Typedef here only acts to make reading the code harder.

Comment: @Blank: No, it serves to make the code *easier* to read: you don't need to include the 'struct' key when naming the type.  (F and T are horrible names, however.)  Typedef also plays no part in hiding content from external users (which I understand you as meaning other TUs).

Comment: @Roger: I disagree on the basis that you are required then to *remember* the actual type of all these typedefs.  Also, if typedef is being used and used only to remove the use of the keyword struct (which, I have to say, seems crazy!  what other keywords do we want to eliminate?  at what point does the language stop looking like C?), what confusion arises when we then have typedefs which actually really are not structs?

Comment: @Blank: Does FILE confuse you?

Comment: @Blank: Must you express your disgust every single time someone uses `typedef struct` on SO?!

Comment: @Roger: FILE is one of the rare examples of a typdef properly used - this most likely because it's part of the standard, and they knew to get it right.  The only operations you perform on that type are via function calls.  This is how typedef operations must be conducted - or else you are requiring the reader to remember the underlying type of the typedef, which completely negates the original purpose of using a typedef (assuming it's used for abstraction, as opposed to modifying the language syntax!)

Comment: @Oli: if you'd seen the code I've worked with, you'd have the same reaction :-)

Comment: @Blank: I would be genuinely interested to see some code where this has actually caused a problem/confusion!

Comment: @Oli: the problem was that most things were typedefed, but then operated on *with knowledge of the underlying type*, e.g. addition, loops, comparison, etc.  So coming to any given file or function, you had a bunch of variables declared, where you didn't know their types (all typedefs) and then you had to try to read the code... so you went back, of course, and looked up all their types - and then had to keep that in your mind, while trying also to comprehend the code.

Comment: @Blank: But even if you don't use `typedef` (i.e. you use `struct blah` directly), you still have to look up e.g. the struct definition!  As long as you declare the typedef at the same type as the struct definition, I can't see how this could cause a problem.

Comment: @Blank: Using 'struct' wouldn't help that situation *at all.* You'd still have to go back and look up the types to understand how the variables are being used.  Does va_list, another typedef in the stdlib, confuse you?  How about int8_t, et. al.?  Bad code certainly isn't helped with *or* without typedef, but good code can be better with — and bad code *isn't worse* with it either, unless you purposefully obfuscate.

Comment: @Oli & Roger: you're thinking only of structs.  Most things were typedefed.  Moreover, I find I almost never use structs and directly manipulate their members.  Structs typically represent the state of an instantiation and they are operated on via functions.

Comment: @Roger: BTW, va_list does confuse me.  I don't know if it's a pointer or not.  If I pass it to a function, can I pass it directly, or will I be passing a large amount of data over the stack?  or should I be passing its address?

Comment: @Blank: There's your answer: for the code you mentioned, you found it to be bad because it broke encapsulation (and directly manipulated several different members), *not* because it used typedef.

Comment: @Blank: All good points about how the implementation-specific details of varargs make portable code more difficult, but *none* of them would be solved, or even improved, if you had to write 'struct va_list' instead!  (Yes, I picked a particularly troublesome part of the stdlib to set you up for that.  BTW, you can pass it directly; C99 §7.15.)

Comment: @Roger: if I had to write struct va_list, I would know it to be a struct (rather than say a pointer), and I would know I would want to pass its address in a function call.

Comment: @Blank: No, even if you knew it wasn't a pointer, you still must follow the va_start/va_copy/va_end requirements — and they can't be narrowed down in the non-pointer case.

Comment: @Roger: manipulating structure members does not in and of itself break encapsulation - it only does so if the members are supposed not to be manipulated; and the problem described was of not being able to know the type of variables, because they were obscured by a typedef but used as if they were not.  This is one of the things which I'm getting at - typedefs are IME (and in the case of the OP) used purportedly for encapsulation *but then the variables are used in a way which breaks encapsulation*.  Certainly you can avoid doing this, but the problem is that I have never seen it happen.

Comment: @Roger: I don't understand what you're saying about following va_start/copy/end requirements.  Do you mean that their prototype must be honoured?

Comment: @Blank: I'm sorry your experience with C code has been so poor, but I don't believe you can blame it on typedef.  I'll cut that thread short here, for some reason (perhaps ENOCOFFEE) we're not on the same page.  See §7.15 in C99 for varargs requirements.

Answer (score 3):

```
T t[] =
{
    { &f->l }
};
```

The address of an element (e.g. &f->l) is only known at run-time.

Such a value cannot be used for compile-time initialization (which is what's being done here).

Comment: Yes that makes sense. But what if i would define f as a const pointer to the 'magic address'; `F* const f = (F*) 0x08000100;`

Comment: Then you've cast an integer value into a pointer.  That's viable as a compile-time init.  However, unless you have a hardware register or somesuch, it's hard to see it being useful?

Comment: The address is a hardware location, namely memory mapped eeprom. Of-course the example above is just for discussion's sake, if i had to implement it this way i would define a macro with the eeprom address in a hardware depended header file and use that macro for the initialization of the pointer; `F* const f = (F*) EEPROM_BASE;`. Anyway the compiler does not seem to accept this either, it's still giving the same compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

The t[] array cannot be filled out until runtime - because the address of F isn't known until runtime.

You could initialize T[] to {NULL} and patch it in post-init.

Another approach is to initialize the members of T to just simply be the offset within the structure, and after you init f, to walk through the array and adjust the pointer locations by adding the address of f.  This technique is similar to what is often used in linking.

Something like this:

```
#define MEMBER_OFFSET_OF(a,b) &(((a*)0)->b)

T t[] = 
{
   {(long*)MEMBER_OFFSET_OF(F, l)}
};
const int numElementsInT = sizeof(t) / sizeof(t[0]);

void init()
{
 f = (F*) 0x08000100; 
 for (int i= 0; i < numElementsInT; i++)
 {
   t[i].lp += (unsigned int)f;
 }  
}
```

Comment: +1: That's a neat `MEMBER_OFFSET_OF` macro. Didn't see this before. :)

Comment: What's wrong with the standard offsetof macro?  (It even does the right thing with type and parentheses.)

Comment: Actually, there's a worse problem here: `t[i].lp += (unsigned)f`.  That is not the same as `t[i].lp = (long*)((unsigned)t[i].lp + (unsigned)f)`, which does what you describe in the text.

Comment: Good find - pointer arithmetic would be adding sizeof(long) * offset instead of just the offset.  I was intending this as pseudocode so I didn't bother compiling or testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking for a C90 compiler there is no way around this. For the initialization idiom,

*declarator* = *initialization sequence*

the initialization sequence needs to be a constant expression, i.e. one which can be computed at compile-time or at link-time. So,

```
int a;
int *b[] = { &a };
```

works, while

```
void foo() {
    int a;
    int *b[] = { &a };
}
```

will not because the address of the automatic a isn't computable before runtime.

If you switch to C99, the latter will work. Your code however still is beyond what a C99 compiler can precompute. If you switch to C++ your code would work, at least Comeau doesn't object.
Edit: of course Roger is correct in that this doesn't solve your problem of having an incorrect dereferencing through a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets imagine that you could use non-constant data to initialize a global: you still have a huge problem.

When t is initialized, f still has an indeterminate value: this happens *before* init() executes and assigns your magic address.  Because of this, even if you could use `&f->l`, you'd have to reset all places it's been used, anyway.